# a problem in concatenating arrays in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, concatenation

I have a multidimensional matrix (10 * 59 * 2000) and I want to concatenate my 10 trials in a signal. The final matrix should look likes (590*2000). I have tried several methods.

when I use the following code I get an error:

```
M = np.array([])
for i in range(0, 10)):
    m1 = raw._data[i]
    M = np.concatenate(([M, m1]), axis = 0)
```

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

When I use the other code which suggested [Here](http://akuederle.com/create-numpy-array-with-for-loop) I get the same error

```
M = np.empty((59, 2000))
for i in range(0, 10):
    m1 = raw._data[i]
    M = np.append(M, [m1], axis = 0)
```

But when I change [m1] to m1 I can get a good result but instead of getting (590*2000) the result is (649*2000) that exactly an empty array (59*2000) which I made in the first line added to my final matrix.

```
M = np.append(M, m1, axis = 0)
```

Could you please let me know how can I concatenate these arrays in a loop to make my destination array (590*2000)?

Comment: Can't you just `reshape` the matrix? Also, please add a (small!) example of the input matrix.

Comment: I don't think so. it's 10 trials of an EEG signal which made a 3D matrix as I said above and now I want to concatenate all 10 trials and make a 2D signal.

Comment: Just `reshape` the matrix.

Comment: How? by not trying to do this in the first place.  As you found out it is hard to get the initial array right.  And it is slow.  Collect the arrays in a list, and do one concatenate at the end.

Comment: You did not read the linked article correctly.  The correct initial array was `np.empty((0, 100))`.  Even then it acknowledged that the process was slow.

Comment: when I use `np.empty((0,100))` I get an error about dimension that is why I changed it to `np.empty((59,2000))`.

Comment: @Well, of course, since none of your dimensions is 100, but the crucial part if the 0 in the other dimension. You are appending to a matrix that already has the desired final size. Try `np.empty((0, 2000))` or something like that. But as I said, `reshape` should work and is probably faster.

Comment: I have tried `np.empty((0, 2000))` before but I got the same error. For reshaping, I explained in answer 1. There is a problem

Answer (score 0):

I assume your shape is 10 trials, 59 eeg channels and 2000 time points.

You want the time dimension concatenated with a resulting shape of 59, 20 * 2000.

```
np.concatenate(multi_trial, axis=1)
# or
np.hstack(multit_trial)
```

What this does: split multi_trial on first axis ( the trials one) . With all the arrays it gets, one (channel, time) array for each trial, glue them together along the second axis, the temporal one.

Comment: Yes, Mihai you are right about the data. I have 10 trials of 64ch *2000 sample, Finally, I want to create 64*20000. I have no problem with concatenating one by one but it doesn't work well in a loop. I can do that in Matlab easily but in python, I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Does np.hstack not work? Are you sure you have a numpy array?

Answer (score 0):

If we must concatenate iteratively:

```
In [84]: rdata = np.arange(24).reshape(4,3,2)
In [85]: M = np.empty((0,2), int)
    ...: for i in range(4):
    ...:     M = np.concatenate((M, rdata[i,:,:]),axis=0)
    ...:     
In [86]: M
Out[86]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11],
       [12, 13],
       [14, 15],
       [16, 17],
       [18, 19],
       [20, 21],
       [22, 23]])
```

I get the same thing with `rdata.reshape(12,2)` and with

```
In [89]: M = []
    ...: for i in range(4):
    ...:     M.append(rdata[i,:,:])
    ...: M = np.concatenate(M, axis=0)
```

Even with this small sample the list append 2+ times faster than the array concatenate.

I don't have to iterate - just pass `rdata` to concatenate.  It treats the 3d array as a list of 2d array:

```
np.concatenate(rdata, axis=0)
```

Note that I use `concatenate`.  I can't say enough bad things about `np.append`.  It's ok if you want to add a scalar to the end of a 1d array, but for anything else it's harder to use, and misleads users in many ways.  `concatenate` takes a whole list of items, `append` just accepts 2.

There are other covers for `concatenate` that are useful in their own ways.  `np.stack` is perhaps the best.  But in the long run you won't use the 'stacks' right unless you understand how to manipulate dimensions and use `concatenate` directly.

MATLAB does allow you to grow an array incrementally.  I suspect though that in the background it is doing a lot of the same new array copying that `numpy` does.  Python lists are better because they don't involve copies.  List append just adds a pointer to the lists buffer, so it is fast and simple. A quick web search shows that even in MATLAB, dynamically growing a matrix is discouraged; most recommend preallocating the matrix.

numpy concatenate from a list is a bit like MATLAB `cell2mat`.  `cell`, like `list` can contain objects of differing kinds, while a `matrix` has uniform numeric content.